# Cloud Flight Coding Contest - Mars Rover

Tags: python, trigonometry

Doing the Mars Rover coding problem and am stuck at level 2. Trying to debug but I just can't see it and it wont let me progress until current level is finished.

**Problem Description as follows:**

Calculate the position and the direction of the rover after driving a certain distance with a certain steering angle.

Input: WheelBase, Distance, SteeringAngle (2 decimal floats)
Output: X, Y, NewDirection Angle

Example:
In: 1.00 1.00 30.00
Out: 0.24 0.96 28.65

Anybody know of any links to some walk throughs, solutions etc or more examples?

There is an image link to the coding problem at the bottom

Thanks

https://catcoder.codingcontest.org/training/1212/play

```
## Level 1 - calculate the turn radius ##
## level1 2 - calculate new position and angle
import math


## solution works for this data
WHEELBASE = 1.00
DISTANCE = 1.00
STEERINGANGLE = 30.00

#WHEELBASE = 1.75
#DISTANCE = 3.14
#STEERINGANGLE = -23.00


def calculateTurnRadius(wheelbase, steeringangle):
    return round(wheelbase / math.sin(math.radians(steeringangle)), 2)

def calculateNewDirection(wheelbase, steeringangle, distance):
    turnRadius = calculateTurnRadius(wheelbase, steeringangle)
    theta = distance / turnRadius

    #brings theta to within a 180 arc
    while theta >= math.pi * 2:
        theta -= math.pi * 2

    while theta < 0:
        theta += math.pi * 2

    # calculate theta with basic sin and cos trig
    x = turnRadius - (math.cos(theta) * turnRadius)
    y = math.sin(theta) * turnRadius
    
    x = abs(round(x, 2))
    y = round(y, 2)
    theta = math.degrees(theta)

    theta = round(theta, 2)

    return x, y, theta


print(f"Turn Radius = {calculateTurnRadius(WHEELBASE, STEERINGANGLE)}")
print(f"{calculateNewDirection(WHEELBASE, STEERINGANGLE, DISTANCE)}")

Turn Radius = 2.0
(0.24, 0.96, 28.65)

 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDY2u.jpg
```

Comment: Please clarify what exactly it is you're having trouble.  Links to questions could potentially break in the future, so summarizing what you need to do and what your trouble is, would help.  If you're having errors, please include the traceback errors.

Comment: Turning radius is `wheelbase / tan(steering_angle)`, not `sin`.  Why are you rounding the values?

Comment: Thanks for replying:0

I am just following the formulas given to me in the problem and have been asked to round to 2 digits.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't really looked at your code, but I got the solutions from level 1 to 4. So here's my code for level 2.

```py
import math

def turn_radius(wheel_base, steering_angle):
    radius: float = wheel_base/math.sin(math.radians(steering_angle))
    print (f"{radius:.2f}")

    return radius

def get_position(distance, steering_angle, radius):
    angle = (distance*180)/(math.pi*radius)
    y = (math.sin(math.radians(angle)) * radius)
    x = radius - (math.cos(math.radians(angle)) * radius)

    while angle < 0:
        angle = 360 + angle
    
    if angle == 360:
        angle = 0

    print(f"{x:.2f} {y:.2f} {angle:.2f}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    wheel_base = 2.7
    distance = 45
    steering_angle = -34

    if steering_angle == 0:
        steering_angle = 360

    radius = turn_radius(wheel_base ,steering_angle)
    get_position(distance, steering_angle, radius)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also stuck, but what I have so far works for the first 2 inputs:

```
import math

WheelBase, Distance, SteeringAngle = 1, 1, 30.00
WheelBase, Distance, SteeringAngle = 2.13, 4.30, 23.00

WheelBase = float(WheelBase)
Distance = float(Distance)
SteeringAngle = float(SteeringAngle)

TurnRadius = abs(WheelBase / math.sin(math.pi * (SteeringAngle) / 180))

NewDirection = 180 * (Distance / TurnRadius) / math.pi

chord = 2 * TurnRadius * math.sin(math.pi * NewDirection / 360)

y = TurnRadius * math.sin(math.pi * (NewDirection) / 180)

x = math.sqrt(chord ** 2 - y ** 2)

print(round(x, 2), round(y, 2), round(NewDirection, 2))

print(chord)
print(math.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2))
```